# Can I reencrypt my GPG private key with more password rounds?

Tags: gnupg

As noted [elsewhere](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39896/how-to-get-a-million-rounds-of-pkcs8-pbkdf2-with-openssl), SSH private keys can be reencrypted (in different formats) with more rounds of iteration in the password-derivation function.

Is there a way to do something similar for an already extant GPG private key? Can I simply modify it to require more rounds of password derivation to make it harder to bruteforce?

Comment: Of course you could take an interpretation of this and then modify it youself. I await to hear the response if this question.

Answer (score 3):

From what I read in the [GnuPG manual](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Invoking-GPG.html#Invoking-GPG), you may use `--edit-key` and the `passwd` subcommand to change the passphrase on your key; if an iteration count was provided on the command-line with `--s2k-count`, then the new password hashing *should* use the specified count.

(I have not tried it; this is just theoretical.)

Comment: Any ideas on how to verify if it works?

Comment: Set it to a very high value, and see if it makes usage slower... Otherwise, inspect the file contents, with an hexadecimal dump of the file, and reading RFC 4880.