# How do I determine if an existing SSH private key is secure?

Tags: ssh, openssh

For an ordinary user, how would I verify that a private key file was generated using reasonably secure algorithms? In response to things like [allegedly insecure ssh-keygen defaults](https://latacora.singles/2018/08/03/the-default-openssh.html).

Comment: On *nix systems, `grep BEGIN ~/.ssh/id_*` ... If it **doesn't** have OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY ... then you have the old format keys. .... I typically use my PGP keys through ssh-agent and let GPG handle the key management.

Comment: @RubberStamp Assuming that an ordinary user has no idea what "old format" means, how would they know what that means and whether it's secure or not?

Comment: Related... and [possible dup](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39279/stronger-encryption-for-ssh-keys) ... try `openssl asn1parse -in -` ...

Comment: @RubberStamp @TomLeek is able to read that output, but I'm not. The `man` page just says "Some knowledge of the ASN.1 structure is needed to interpret the output." I wouldn't know where to begin to establish within a reasonable amount of time what the KDF is, for example.

Comment: @RubberStamp+ asn1parse doesn't work at all on either kind of encrypted privatekey file ssh-keygen can create, neither the OpenSSL 'traditional' format with PEM-level encryption nor the OpenSSH 'new' format with body-level encryption but non-ASN.1 encoding (instead XDR-like)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 ... >ans1parse doesn't work on encrypted... *That's why `openssl` prompts for the passphrase when one attempts to do so...* My fist comment, now your answer, was the quick and easy way to test and given key... My second comment, linked to the very excellent and detailed Q/A from 5 years ago, shows how to dissect a key if one knows the passphrase.

Comment: @RubberStamp: `openssl rsa`, `openssl pkey`, and other operations that internally call `PEM_read_*PrivateKey`, prompt for the password when needed; `openssl asn1parse` does not, and can't decrypt even if you could give it a password. Plus OpenSSL can't handle OpenSSH-newformat encryption at all. The Bear's answer at your link (as you say, and as usual, excellent) doesn't use the password to 'dissect' anything; it does use `asn1parse` to show the _unencrypted_ metadata for PKCS8, but ssh-keygen never writes PKCS8. I agree it is a pretty good dupe for the Q, though.

Comment: >openssl asn1parse does not, and can't decrypt even if you could give it a password..... *The magic of piping... `openssl rsa -in mykey.pem | openssl asn1parse -in -` ... I did not write that the passphrase is used to dissect anything. Please quote exactly if you wish to quote.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As RubberStamp points out, this is covered in detail in [stronger encryption for SSH keys](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39279/stronger-encryption-for-ssh-keys) but to summarize:

**Look at the words in the first line, and the next one or two.**

```
 -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
 Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
 DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC,(hex)

 (several lines of base64)
 -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

(or similarly with `DSA PRIVATE KEY` or `EC PRIVATE KEY`) is the old, bad-PBKDF format.

```
 -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- # or DSA,EC
 (base64 immediately)
 -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY----- # ditto
```

is the old *unencrypted* format, which is even worse.

```
 -----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
 (several lines of base64)
 -----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
```

is the OpenSSH-specific 'new' format, which is why it *says* `OPENSSH` right there. However, this format doesn't directly show whether it's encrypted or not. The easiest way is to try reading it (either for an `ssh` connection, or with `ssh-keygen` to convert or modify it) and see if it needs a password. Alternatively, you can strip the labels and decode the base64 (conveniently, `openssl base64 -d` does *both* of these!) and look at it:

```
$ openssl base64 -d <se200935.clr |od -c
0000000   o   p   e   n   s   s   h   -   k   e   y   -   v   1  \0  \0
0000020  \0  \0 004   n   o   n   e  \0  \0  \0 004   n   o   n   e  [snip rest]

$ openssl base64 -d <se200935.enc |od -c
0000000   o   p   e   n   s   s   h   -   k   e   y   -   v   1  \0  \0
0000020  \0  \0  \n   a   e   s   2   5   6   -   c   b   c  \0  \0  \0
0000040 006   b   c   r   y   p   t [snip rest]
```

Comment: So is the "new OpenSSH-specific format" considered secure or not? I don't get this from your answer unfortunately.

Comment: @bers: Yes, OpenSSH 'new' format -- IF encrypted (see edit) -- uses bcrypt with sane parameters, which is a good PBKDF. It also uses good symmetric encryption, but that's not a differentiator, even OpenSSH 'old' format which is OpenSSL 'traditional' format does that.

Comment: This hex dumping answer is great. A small simplification that's easier on the eyes is to use strings instead. E.g. `openssl base64 -d < ~/.ssh/id_rsa | strings`

Comment: `hexdump -C` is a very readable alternative.